# Would SQS batch size max limit result in slower processing through Lambdas?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm aware that AWS has allowed SQS to be one of the event source mappings for Lambdas. I'm glad that this is possible now as I would then not have to poll from the queue every few seconds through a cron job. However, it appears that the maximum possible value for `batchSize` is limited to 10. From my understanding, the `batchSize` is the number of messages a single Lambda invocation will receive from the queue.

This sounds like it could be an issue for me because, in my case, I may have a few hundreds of thousands of messages at a time in the queue. Those messages don't need any heavy processing; they just need to be parsed and saved to the database as a record. It's pretty simple.

If the `batchSize` is limited to only 10 messages per retrieval, I foresee a few issues that I may have:

1. It may actually take a long time to finish processing the messages on the queue.
2. Not only is 10 messages per retrieval slow, since the messages are very simple to process, processing only 10 messages in a single Lambda invocation sounds a little wasteful because, given the simplicity of what is needed to be done to process the messages, I'm pretty sure it can process at least a few thousands messages in a single Lambda invocation.
3. Having only 10 messages per retrieval may also mean that I need to make more write operations to my database because each of these messages need to inserted as a record on the database.

Are my concerns valid in this case? If so, is there anything else I can do with SQS and Lambdas to overcome those concerns?

Comment: SQS has been able to trigger Lambda for almost 2 years, so I'm not sure 'recent' is the right description. The max batch size is indeed 10, but Lambda will invoke multiple Lambdas concurrently. You need to be sure that your backend DB can handle the number of concurrent connections / writes if you do this because it's often the DB that's the performance issue here

Comment: @jarmod Yes you are right, "recent" probably isn't the best description in this case. As for the DB performance, this is precisely one of the reasons I'm concerned about the 10 messages limit because this will essentially mean that I'm making more connections concurrently to the database as I could only write 10 records to the database at every one time. If I could somehow increase the `batchSize` to 1000 for example, I could reduce the number of connections to write the database.

Comment: If your DB is on RDS then look at the RDS Proxy. If the DB is Aurora Serverless then look at the Data API. You can also throttle an individual Lambda by limiting its concurrency, which can make sense in some scenarios. Not saying its ideal for your case, but something to be aware of if you take some measurements and realize that limiting the number of concurrent DB connections would be a viable solution for you.

Comment: @Carven Maybe then for your situation it would make more sense to poll the queue and - if any messages found - receive them all until no messages left, then write them all in one go. Of course this assumes the time between message being received in the queue and your lambda processing it is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption about a limit of 10 [is correct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateEventSourceMapping.html#API_CreateEventSourceMapping_RequestSyntax).

Lambda will spin up more instances to run in parallel, if there are more messages available. See [Scaling and Processing.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) This means that if there are 1000 messages available, Lambda might spin up 100 concurrent executions to quickly process all the messages.

Once a lambda function has processed the 10 messages of a batch, it continues with processing other batches. As lambda bills in 100ms intervals, the wasted time is minimal.

As for the database writes you could pre-process the messages before inserting them into the queue.

Comment: Yes, I will be preprocessing the messages before inserting them. Unfortunately, the maximum records I can insert at one time is still limited to 10 records per write operation because of the `batchSize` limit.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you need to let you lambda function fetch the messages from the queue and process them rather than lambda getting triggered via SQS. Probably have a cloud watch event which can trigger lambda for you depending upon what your use case is.

Please note that SQS has a limit of max 10 messages in one go but you could write the code to make it much more efficient.

One of the package which is very efficient at is [squiss-ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/squiss-ts)

In this case you could let your lambda function run for 15 mins (max time) and let it process as many messages possible. Idempotency is the key when you are desinging these kind of applications so in case if message wasn't processed in this run, it will be processed in the next run.

Downside of using this approach is that you need to scale your lambda's manually depending on how many messages you are anticipating.

Comment: If I was using CloudWatch event to trigger the Lambda which checks for messages from SQS, how do I manually scale this particular Lambda to run concurrently when I anticipate a high volume of messages on the queue? I suppose CloudWatch event is only able to trigger one Lambda invocation at every interval, right?

Comment: there is no direct way tbh. You need to have cloudwatch event which gets triggers lets says every 5 mins which in turn trigger a lambda function which could send 1000s of messages to sns and which can trigger your lambda function. But again as I said before, you need to maintain this by yourself and it also depends on how dynamic is your load. Good thing is you will have full control over how many you fetch and how many you send in bulk. I would argue that it might be better performance wise as more things in parallel and in batch.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that a larger batch size seems appropriate for your use case.

[As of late 2020](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/11/aws-lambda-now-supports-batch-windows-of-up-to-5-minutes-for-functions/), if you specify a batch window in seconds, you can then specify a batch size of up to 10,000 messages.

So with this new option you can now configure your lambda to wait and receive much larger batches per invocation.